# mongodb filter for date comparison

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

From a spring boot application I am querying a mongodb collection to find out active agreements on a particular day. There is no change in data and there are 31 unique agreements. When I run it for past 7 days it gives me correct count for 5 days, but for yesterday & today it give me a count of 30.Actually all the agreements in collection are valid. There are multiple documents with same agreement id - to remove duplicates I have used grouping.
My code is like this:

```
public int getTotalActivePAsORActiveItemsByDate(LocalDate date1) {
    String collectionName = Constants.AGREEMENT_COLLECTION_NAME;
    final List<Bson> pipeline = new ArrayList<>();
    Bson q1 = match(Filters.and(Filters.eq("agreementStatus", "Active")));
    pipeline.add(q1);
    if(date1 != null) {
        Bson q2 = match(and(lte("validFromDate", date1), gte("validToDate", date1)));
        pipeline.add(q2);
    }
    String project = "{$project:{agreementId:1, " + "validFromDate:1, " + "validToDate: 1 " + "}}";
    pipeline.add(BasicDBObject.parse(project));
    String addUpStr = "{$group:{" + "_id:'$agreementId', " + "count :{'$sum':1} " + "}}";
    pipeline.add(BasicDBObject.parse(addUpStr));
    String cntStr = "{$group:{_id:null, val:{'$sum':1}}}";
    pipeline.add(BasicDBObject.parse(cntStr));
    MongoDatabase mongo = mongoTemplate.getDb();
    final AggregateIterable<Document> ret = mongo.getCollection(collectionName).aggregate(pipeline);
    int val = 0;
    try {
        val = ret.first().getInteger("val");
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    return val;
}
```

And a sample document:

```
{_id=600ae734d752d67e519a34b6, 
 agreementStatus=Active, 
 validFromDate=Wed Oct 01 05:30:00 IST 2014, 
 validToDate=Sun Mar 31 05:30:00 IST 2024, 
 agreementId=VPC_BF_NW_Hu_LU70_NSO_MULT_400002129_D57E911804B9
```

}

The whole problem stems from date. Is mongodb failing in date comparison?

Comment: **Never** store date/time values as string, it's a design flaw. Store proper `Date` object, then your query will work.

Comment: @Wernfried , actually in mongodb it has been stored as date field only. There is nothing wrong in code or database. One agreement expired on 21st Jan, 2021. So no of agreements before 21st Jan was 31 and now it is 30. However though my question was invalid, thanks for sharing valuable tip.

Comment: Can you print the generated pipeline? You mixed direct `Bson.add()` and `BasicDBObject.parse`. Is there any specific reason for that?